# How can I use origin_set on arbitrary objects instead of the selected ones?

Tags: python, origin

I have this very simple code here:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
import mathutils
from mathutils import Vector

curve = "CurvObj"
mold = "MoldObj"
mol = bpy.data.objects[mold]
cur = bpy.data.objects[curve]



group = mol.vertex_groups[0]

mwCur = cur.matrix_world
mwMol = mol.matrix_world


vg_idx = 0
moldVerts = [ v1 for v1 in mol.data.vertices if vg_idx in [ vg.group for vg in v1.groups ] ]
curvVerts = [ v2 for v2 in cur.data.vertices if vg_idx in [ vg.group for vg in v2.groups ] ]





#    Moves 3D cursor to vertex location
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = mwMol @ moldVerts[0].co

#    Set object origin to 3D cursor
bpy.ops.mol.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')

# I also tried this, to no avail:
mol.data.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
```

But it is giving the error "Calling operator "bpy.ops.mol.origin_set" error, could not be found"

How do I access origin_set with my object? I do not want to use the *selected* object in the scene- so is there any way to do this without selecting the object first? If that's the only solution then let me know.

Comment: I know, but doesn't that use the currently selected object? Like I mentioned that's not what I want - I want the previously defined object, mol.

Comment: That is what I said. bpy.ops.object_origin_set sets the origin on the selected object. I do not have a selected object and that is not what I want. Instead, I want it to be a previously defined object, which is not currently selected.

Comment: I'm trying to say that you can't have what you want.  The available tool for setting the origin is a `bpy.ops.object` tool and those tools work on the selected object.

Comment: You didn't say that it's impossible, you just kept repeating yourself. Anyway, so I need to select the object first, then run that code, and then unselect the object. Thank you.

Comment: No you don't need to do that. You just need to use an override in the operator, but you have to use the correct operator.

Comment: @Gorgious could you tell me how to do that? I tried to research this as much as I could but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an [override](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) if you want to move the origin of arbitrary objects instead of the selected ones.

```
import bpy

moved_objects = [bpy.data.objects["Cube"], ]  # You can add any editable objects here

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(
    {"selected_editable_objects": moved_objects},
    type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', 
    center='MEDIAN'
)
```

**Note :**

Starting with Blender Version 3.2+ you should use this syntax for operator overrides :

```
with bpy.context.temp_override(selected_editable_objects=moved_objects):
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
```

Comment: Interesting update... Should add-ons be updated accordingly?

Comment: @Crantisz According to this [patch](https://developer.blender.org/rBf438344cf243632e497772cf1f855b9c8856fd37) the dictionary method has been deprecated. I think it will throw warnings in the console for 1 or 2 releases, then they will remove this method altogether. So, the answer is yes I guess, but not in a hurry